# send email in listview

Tags: email, send

```
 package com.example.decnail.decnail;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient;
import com.loopj.android.http.FileAsyncHttpResponseHandler;
import com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;

import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header;

import static android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.*;

public class TareaArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Tarea> {

    private Picasso picasso;
    public Bitmap bitmap;
    customButtonListener customListner;


    public TareaArrayAdapter(Context context, List<Tarea> objects) {
        super(context, 0, objects);
    }



    public interface customButtonListener {
        public void onButtonClickListner(int position,String value);
    }

    public void setCustomButtonListner(customButtonListener listener) {
        this.customListner = listener;
    }




    //override es automatico
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.itemlista, null, true);
        //Obteniendo una instancia del inflater el layout con los items nombre y hora


        //Salvando la referencia del View de la fila
        View listItemView = convertView;

        Log.i("imagen", "adapter vamos bien ");



        ImageView image2 = (ImageView)listItemView.findViewById(R.id.image1);
        TextView txt_descrip = (TextView)listItemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_descripcion);
        Button correo = (Button)listItemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_enviar);

        //Obteniendo instancia de la Tarea en la posición actual
        final Tarea item = getItem(position);

        txt_descrip.setText(item.getDescrip());

        Picasso.with(getContext())
                .load(item.getImage())
                .resize(400, 600)
                .into(image2);






       correo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {


               Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
               intent.setType("*/*");

               intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "unab99@gmail.com");
               intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "envio");
               intent.setType("message/rfc822");
               // intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, attachment);
               startActivity(intent,"enviar");


               Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getContext(), item.getImage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
               toast.show();
               String to = "toast";
               Log.i("Toast", to);


           }
       });







        return listItemView;





    }











        //Devolver al ListView la fila creada


 }
```

but i have this error

in  startActivity(intent,"enviar");

Error:(104, 29) error: method startActivity in class ActivityCompat cannot be applied to given types;
required: Activity,Intent,Bundle
found: Intent,String
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

so i dont what i do

Answer (score 0):

i resolve the problem

only is necesary , getcontext like that:

getContext().startActivity(intent);